# Is it possible to derive nested class from generic type provided by outer class?

Tags: delphi, generics

I'd like to create a nested class which is based on the type provided to the outer class. I need the inner class to extend `T` by some members:

```
TOuterClass<T:class> = class
  type
    TNestedClass = class(T)
      MoreData:Integer;
    end;
end;
```

The compiler says "No" or more specifically *[DCC Error] MyUnit.pas(20): E2021 Class type required* at `class(T)`.

Is it somehow possible to achieve what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, that's not possible.

Answer (score 2):

Not yet.  It probably should, but the compiler doesn't really think through all the ramifications of generic constraints yet.  You should add this into QC as a feature request.

Answer (score 0):

No but you can in a derived class that has resolved the type of T:

```
TOuterClass<T:class> = class
  //Data
end;

TDerived = class(TOuterClass<TObject>)
  type
    TNestedClass = class(TObject)
      MoreData:Integer;
    end;
end;
```